# Why is Angular's Renderer2 producing the wrong results?

Tags: angular

I have an array of questions, each containing underscores at different positions like this:

1. Newton’s __________ Law of Motion states
2. __________ is the product of an object’s mass and velocity.

etc.

My task is to display each question to the user, replacing the underscores with an input box such that they can insert their answers to the questions.

A walkthrough of the directive I created to create the html replacing the underscores.

In the directive, we get the native element that invokes the directive.

```
const nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
```

The native element looks like this in the html, a span containing an input element.

```
 <span class="fw-semibold primary-color" [appReplaceUnderscores]="fillInBlank.question">
        <input [(ngModel)]="userAnswer"
            class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField d-inline" 
            type="text" 
            required 
            name="userAnswer" 
            placeholder="Enter your answer here" 
            (change)="processAnswer()" 
            [disabled]="answer !== null">
    </span>
```

The next segment of code iterates over the native element and removes every span that is a child of the native element but keeps the input element.

```
nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(node => {
  console.log('node.nodeName', node.nodeName)

  if(node.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    inputNode = node;
    console.log('inputNode', inputNode)
    console.log('typeOf inputNode', typeof inputNode)
  }
  
  if(node.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
    this.renderer.removeChild(nativeElement, node)   
  }      
})
```

My tests show that the above segment of code that removes the SPAN nodes is inconsistent. This is one occurrence that code is executed. One SPAN node is still present.

```
<span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="fw-semibold primary-color">
  <input _ngcontent-msf-c27="" type="text" required="" 
    name="userAnswer" placeholder="Enter your answer here" 
    class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField d-inline ng-dirty ng-touched 
        ng-invalid">
    <span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="d-inline"> 
      Law of Motion states that for every....
    </span>
</span>
```

The next segment of code is supposed to attach one span before the input element and another after the input element. It too is behaving inconsistently.

```
this.renderer.insertBefore(nativeElement, spanBeforeInput, inputNode)
console.log('nativeElement after child prepended', nativeElement)

// spanBeforeInput?.before(inputNode)
// spanAfterInput?.after(inputNode)
this.renderer?.appendChild(nativeElement, spanAfterInput);
```

In this instance, it appended both SPAN nodes after the input node.

```
<span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="fw-semibold primary-color">
  <input _ngcontent-msf-c27="" type="text" required="" 
    name="userAnswer" placeholder="Enter your answer here" 
    class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField d-inline 
      ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid">
  <span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="d-inline"> 
   Law of Motion states that for every...
  </span>
  <span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="d-inline">Newton’s Law of </span>
  <span _ngcontent-msf-c27="" class="d-inline"> 
   states that every object...
  </span>
</span>
```

The entire directive is shown below:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appReplaceUnderscores]'
})
export class ReplaceUnderscoresDirective {
   @Input() set appReplaceUnderscores(question) {
    console.log('question', question)
    this.replaceUnderscore(question)
  }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    private renderer:Renderer2
   ) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  private replaceUnderscore = (question) => {
    const nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    console.log('nativeElement', nativeElement)

    let inputNode:ChildNode = null;

    nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(node => {
      console.log('node.nodeName', node.nodeName)

     if(node.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        inputNode = node;
        console.log('inputNode', inputNode)
        console.log('typeOf inputNode', typeof inputNode)
      } else {
        this.renderer.removeChild(nativeElement, node)   
        console.log('node removed', node)
      }      
    })

    const nativeElementAfterChildrenRemoved = nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    console.log('naativeElement after children removed', nativeElementAfterChildrenRemoved) 

    const splits = question.split('__________')
    console.log('splits', splits)

    const textBeforeUnderscores = this.renderer?.createText(splits[0]);
    const textAfterUnderscores = this.renderer?.createText(splits[1]);

    const spanBeforeInput = this.renderer?.createElement('span');
    this.renderer?.appendChild(spanBeforeInput, textBeforeUnderscores);    
    this.renderer.addClass(spanBeforeInput, "d-inline")
    console.log('spanBeforeInput', spanBeforeInput)

    const spanAfterInput = this.renderer?.createElement('span');
    this.renderer?.appendChild(spanAfterInput, textAfterUnderscores);
    this.renderer.addClass(spanAfterInput, "d-inline")
    console.log('spanAfterInput', spanAfterInput)

    this.renderer.insertBefore(nativeElement, spanBeforeInput, inputNode)
    console.log('nativeElement after child prepended', nativeElement)

    // spanBeforeInput?.before(inputNode)
    // spanAfterInput?.after(inputNode)
    this.renderer?.appendChild(nativeElement, spanAfterInput);  

   console.log('nativeElement after child appended', nativeElement)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to encapsulate nativeElement.childNodes in an Array.from() method. Apparently, it does not return an array thereby causing a problem in deleting the child nodes:

```
   Array.from(nativeElement.childNodes).forEach(node => {
      console.log('node.nodeName', node.nodeName)

 if(node.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
    inputNode = node;
    console.log('inputNode', inputNode)
    console.log('typeOf inputNode', typeof inputNode)
  } else {
    this.renderer.removeChild(nativeElement, node)   
    console.log('node removed', node)
  }      
})
```